# Remove url link found in UItextview when a url is typed in swift 5

Tags: ios

I am using a text view. I want remove if a url is typed inside the text view.I am not able to do that after finding the url present

Comment: "that after finding the url present"? Could you add details on the behavior you want? You want to "remove": Disable what exactly?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the URL only not text

Comment: So it's not about having an URL with "underline and color", it's about disabling user to enter an URL? So you want to find URLs in a String, and remove it?

Comment: I need solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
yourTextView.dataDetectorTypes = []
```

Comment: I am using a text view. I want remove if a url is typing inside the text view.I am not able to do that after finding the url present.
For this what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
    func removingUrls() -> String {
        guard let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue) else {
            return self
        }
        return detector.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self,
                                                 options: [],
                                                 range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count),
                                                 withTemplate: "")
    }
}
```